# Pandas Key Error: 0 while plotting a seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I use the following code to read in a Excel file and plot a boxplot using the seaborn package.

```
import scipy.stats as sps
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
sns.set()


inpath=r"P:\Data.xlsx"

df=pd.read_excel(io=inpath,header=0,sheetname="65051045")
df1=df[df["Gel.Menge"]!=0]["Gel.Menge"]
print(df1)
fig2=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sns.boxplot(data=df1)
sns.swarmplot(data=df1,color="black",alpha=0.5)
plt.title("65051045")
```

the excel table looks like:

```
Gel.Menge   Erf.datum   Freig.
0,000   26.11.2014  26.11.2014
10,000  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
5,000   19.12.2014  08.01.2015
7,000   07.07.2015  17.07.2015
1,000   21.07.2015  22.07.2015
5,000   18.03.2016  22.03.2016
10,000  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
10,000  20.07.2016  21.07.2016
20,000  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
5,000   01.12.2014  01.12.2014
3,000   20.04.2015  20.04.2015
```

If I run the code I get the following error message:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        84 print(df1)
>        85 fig2=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
>   ---> 86 sns.boxplot(data=df1)
>        87 sns.swarmplot(data=df1,color="black",alpha=0.5)
>        88 plt.title("65051045 - Laserschweißen Getriebeabtrieb Rundnaht")
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in
>   boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette,
>   saturation, width, fliersize, linewidth, whis, notch, ax, **kwargs)
>   2173     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
>   2174                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
>   -> 2175                           width, fliersize, linewidth)    2176     2177     if ax is None:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in
>   **init**(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, fliersize, linewidth)
>       424                  width, fliersize, linewidth):
>       425 
>   --> 426         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
>       427         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
>       428
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in
>   establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order,
>   units)
>        94                 if hasattr(data, "shape"):
>        95                     if len(data.shape) == 1:
>   ---> 96                         if np.isscalar(data[0]):
>        97                             plot_data = [data]
>        98                         else:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)
>       599         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
>       600         try:
>   --> 601             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>       602 
>       603             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
>   in get_value(self, series, key)    2426         try:    2427
>   return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
>   -> 2428                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))    2429         except KeyError
>   as e1:    2430             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in
>   ['integer', 'boolean']:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
>   (pandas_libs\index.c:4363)()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
>   (pandas_libs\index.c:4046)()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas_libs\index.c:5085)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
>   (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:13913)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
>   (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:13857)()
>
> KeyError: 0

Suprisingly the plot(df1) command is working and it plots:

```
1     10
2      5
3      7
4      1
5      5
6     10
7     10
8     20
9      5
10     3
Name: Gel.Menge, dtype: int64
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1):

I assume the issue is that I have defined:

```
df1=df[df["Gel.Menge"]!=0]["Gel.Menge"]
```

therewith df1 is no longer a DataFrame and seaborn is going to be confused.

If I change:

```
df1=df[df["Gel.Menge"]!=0]["Gel.Menge"]
```

to

```
df1["Gel.Menge"]=df["Gel.Menge"].where(df["Gel.Menge"]!=0).dropna()
```

and also explicitly define df1 to ba a DataFrame with:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame()
```

the code is working.

The working code looks as follows:

```
inpath=r"P:\Data.xlsx"
df1=pd.DataFrame()  

df=pd.read_excel(io=inpath,header=0,sheetname="65051045")
df1["Gel.Menge"]=df["Gel.Menge"].where(df["Gel.Menge"]!=0).dropna()
print(df1)
fig2=plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sns.boxplot(data=df1)
sns.swarmplot(data=df1,color="black",alpha=0.5)
plt.title("65051045")
```

Comment: I would appreciate if anybody can tell me the real reason for the error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved my problem with

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

the index of my df was not okay