# Fastest way of dropping zeros from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I read in several worksheets of an excel file (> 15 MB) where each sheet has > 10000 columns. Sencondly I choose a single column (consists of only integers), drop all values == 0 from this column and write this column to a new df2. Additionally I calculate the descriptie statistics.

Data looks like this:

```
    Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
0         0.0  26.11.2014  26.11.2014
1        10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2         5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3         7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
4         0.0  21.07.2015  22.07.2015
5         5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6        10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
7         0.0  20.07.2016  21.07.2016
8        20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
9         0.0  01.12.2014  01.12.2014
10        0.0  20.04.2015  20.04.2015
```

The code I use is:

```
inpath=r"P:\Data.xlsx"

df1=pd.DataFrame()

for i in ["67059070","67059075","67060055","Screwing Total"]:
    df=pd.read_excel(io=inpath,header=0,sheetname="{0}".format(i))
    df1["Gel.Menge"]=df["Gel.Menge"].where(df["Gel.Menge"]!=0).dropna()
    print(np.round(df1.mode()))    
    print(np.round(df1.describe())
```

Unfortunately this code is super slow...
is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: Enough to do `df[df["Gel.Menge"] != 0]`

Comment: Or, `df.query("Gel.Menge != 0")`, or `df[df.eval("Gel.Menge != 0")]`

Comment: I miss the sample data. All of the above comments would make a good answer.

Comment: If you have specific problems, I suggest adding your data for more representative examples.

Comment: Also, `df[df["Gel.Menge"].astype(bool)]` =)

Comment: The data are sheets with  numeric data but the file is larger than 15 MB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449689/pandas-key-error-0-while-plotting-a-seaborn-boxplot) and modified.

```
df

    Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
0         0.0  26.11.2014  26.11.2014
1        10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2         5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3         7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
4         0.0  21.07.2015  22.07.2015
5         5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6        10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
7         0.0  20.07.2016  21.07.2016
8        20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
9         0.0  01.12.2014  01.12.2014
10        0.0  20.04.2015  20.04.2015
```

---

**Option 1**
*`boolean indexing`*

```
df[df['Gel.Menge'] != 0]

   Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
1       10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2        5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3        7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
5        5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6       10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
8       20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
```

---

**Option 2**
*`np.where`*

```
m = np.where(df['Gel.Menge'], True, False)
m
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
       False, False], dtype=bool)

df[m]

   Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
1       10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2        5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3        7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
5        5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6       10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
8       20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
```

---

**Option 3**
*`df.query`*

```
c = df['Gel.Menge'] 
df.query('@c != 0')

   Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
1       10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2        5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3        7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
5        5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6       10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
8       20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
```

---

**Option 4**
*`df.eval`*

```
df[df.eval('@c != 0')]

   Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
1       10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2        5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3        7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
5        5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6       10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
8       20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
```

*Note*: Two steps are necessary for `query` and `eval` due to the restrictions with handling column names.

---

**Option 5**
*[`astype(bool)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464135/fastest-way-of-dropping-0-values-from-series#comment79883357_46464135)*

```
df[df['Gel.Menge'].astype(bool)]

   Gel.Menge   Erf.datum      Freig.
1       10.0  06.11.2014  07.11.2014
2        5.0  19.12.2014  08.01.2015
3        7.0  07.07.2015  17.07.2015
5        5.0  18.03.2016  22.03.2016
6       10.0  29.03.2016  31.03.2016
8       20.0  13.10.2016  17.10.2016
```

---

**Performance**

```
print(df.shape)
(110000, 3)
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.79 ms per loop
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.97 ms per loop
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.08 ms per loop
```

Comment: So, what is the fastest way?

Comment: @Zero I was right. Option 5 is the fastest, followed by 2, 1, 3, and 4.